# Changing the class of an object in an arraylist

Tags: java, class, exception, arraylist

Alright so I have a model of a beehive which contains an arraylist of bees called cells. What I want to happen is when a bees health hits 0 it is removed from the arraylist (eggs do not need to eat). Everyday the bees age increases by 1 and if there is enough food it is fed and it's health increases by 1 too (up to a max of 3). If there isn't enough food then the health decreases by 1 (until it hits 0 when it is removed from the arraylist). The bee class is abstract and has subclasses such as egg, larvae, pupa etc. When the egg's age > 3 it turns into a larvae, which in turn will become a pupa at age 7. I am having serious issues with coding this however. I have managed to get the feeding, health increase/ decrease and removal if health hits 0 fine but I can't figure out how to "evolve" my egg into a larvae.

My code:

```
public class Hive {

    ArrayList<Bee> cells = new ArrayList<Bee>();
    //some code omitted

    public void anotherDay(){
        for(int i = 0;i<cells.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(cells.get(i));
            Bee bee = cells.get(i);
            try{
                bee = bee.anotherDay();
            }catch(Exception e){
                cells.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Queen class:

```
public class Queen extends Bee{
//some code omitted

    public Bee anotherDay() throws Exception{
        eat();
        age++;
        if(age%3 == 2){
            hive.addBee(new Egg());
        }
        return this;
    } 

    public boolean eat() throws Exception{
        if(hive.honey >= 2){
            hive.takeHoney(2);
            if(health < 3){
                health++;
            }return true;
        }
            health -= 1;
            if(health == 0){
                throw new Exception(); 
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Egg class (methods in larvae and pupa are similar):

```
public class Egg extends Bee {
//some code omitted
    public Bee anotherDay(){
    age = age++;
    if (age>3){
        return new Larvae();
    }else{
    return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your strategy seems to be to return a Bee object, you can just "replace" the list elements with the returned values.

But there are a couple other things I see. The first is that you are using Exceptions to do program logic. Don't do this. Especially since you are just throwing a blank exception, by doing this you are eating all other exceptions too.

The second is that you're modifying the list while iterating over it. This is generally a bad idea and can even [throw a ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) under some circumstances.

When your Queen lays an egg, the list gets 1 larger. Since your loop is based on the list size, the new egg will be included in the iteration. This means your eggs automatically start out at 1 day old, not 0 days old. The same thing goes for removing dead bees. Removing them while you are iterating can mean that you skip the next bee.

I'm not sure what some of your logic is intended to do, like the stuff in `Queen#eat` but here is an attempt to show a more stable version:

```
public class Hive {

    ArrayList<Bee> cells = new ArrayList<Bee>();

    public void anotherDay() {
        List<Bee> dead = new ArrayList<Bee>();
        int size = cells.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Bee bee = cells.get(i);
            System.out.println(bee);

            // return null if the bee is dead
            if ((bee = bee.anotherDay()) == null) {
                dead.add(cells.get(i));
            } else {
                cells.set(i, bee);
            }
        }

        cells.removeAll(dead);
    }
}

public class Queen extends Bee {

    public Bee anotherDay() {
        eat();
        if (health == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        age++;
        if (age % 3 == 2) {
            hive.addBee(new Egg());
        }

        return this;
    } 

    public boolean eat() {
        if(hive.honey >= 2) {
            hive.takeHoney(2);
            if(health < 3){
                health++;
            }
            return true;
        }
        health -= 1;
        return false;
    }
}
```

You don't have to return null, that is just an obvious choice. You could also have a flag like `isDead()`:

```
class SomeBee extends Bee {

    boolean isDead() {
        return health <= 0;
    }

    Bee anotherDay() {
        eat();
        return this;
    }
}

for (/* i...size */) {
    Bee bee = cells.get(i);
    if ((bee = bee.anotherDay()).isDead()) {
        dead.add(bee);
    }
    cells.set(i, bee);
}
```

Or something like the following:

```
abstract class Bee {
    static final Bee DEAD_BEE = new Bee() {
        @Override
        Bee anotherDay() {
            return this;
        }
    };
}

class SomeBee extends Bee {
    @Override
    Bee anotherDay() {
        if (/* is dead */) {
            return Bee.DEAD_BEE;
        } else {
            ...

class Hive {
    void anotherDay() {
        ...

        for (/*    */) {

            Bee next = bee.anotherDay();
            if (next == Bee.DEAD_BEE) {
                /* it's dead */
            } else {
                ...
```

Your eggs don't get any older because of an error with the incrementing:

```
age = age++;
```

A postfix increment evaluates to the value before incrementing. So this is basically like saying `age = age;`. The increment goes off in to nowhere. In this case just remove the assignment, it is redundant:

```
age++;
```

There's also a prefix increment (`++age`) which evaluates to the value after the increment. Sometimes you do want to increment/decrement a variable and immediately use it so it's an important distinction to know about.

For example you could iterate through an array this way:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < array.length)
    System.out.println(array[i++]);
```

Postfix and prefix increments could be defined as methods like the following:

```
class Primitive_int {
    int val;

    // "++value"
    int prefixIncrement() {
        val = val + 1;
        return val;
    }

    // "value++"
    int postfixIncrement() {
        int old = val;
        val = val + 1;
        return old;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much!! That has been a massive help. However larvae still aren't being added to my hive =/

Comment: No problem. And I assume you're referring to the `if (age % 3) hive.addBee` bit. I don't see a reason for it not to work in the code you've included so it's probably somewhere that you've omitted. Make sure the queen correctly has a reference to the hive.

Comment: No that's for the eggs- very confusing!! At the beginning of your answer you said I could just 'replace' the list item with the returned value as my anotherDay method in queen returns a bee and I thought that cells.set(i, bee) would do that but how ever many days pass the eggs don't become larvae!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Hive {

    ArrayList<Bee> cells = new ArrayList<Bee>();
    //some code omitted

    public void anotherDay(){
        for(int i = 0;i<cells.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(cells.get(i));
            Bee bee = cells.get(i); // bee --> egg
            try{
                bee = bee.anotherDay(); // now bee --> Larve
                cells.set(i,bee); // don't forget to set larve where bee was!
            }catch(Exception e){
                cells.remove(i);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I just tried this and now when the anotherDay() method in hive is run I get an infinite loop for some reason!

Comment: yeah that's what I did =/

Comment: use `cells.set(i, bee)` and it shall work. My bad :)

Comment: ah thanks that has gotten rid of the infinite loop problem. Unfortunately no larvae seem to be adding to the hive =(